# Maximizing the integral of a 2D slice through a 3D discreet, bounded scalar field.

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Given an arbitrary, discreet and regular, bounded scalar field in three dimensions (mapped to whatever bounded domain you like), how would I determine the optimal 2D plane position and normal that slices through this field to maximize the integral of the slice?

The values of the scalar field are also bounded between zero and one.

Is there a known algorithm to do this?